# API title must be specified either as "API_TITLE" app parameter or as "title" spec kwarg

Tags: python, flask

I'm following https://github.com/jetbridge/sls-flask and after the `make init` step I'm getting the following error:

`API title must be specified either as "API_TITLE" app parameter or as "title" spec kwarg.`

Not sure where to set the API title. Flask docs itself doesn't say anything about this being a requirement.

Any pointers would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put it in the app.config like this?

```
app.config['API_TITLE'] = 'My API'
app.config['API_VERSION'] = 'v1'
app.config['OPENAPI_VERSION'] = '3.0.2'
```

source: https://flask-smorest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html